# `FullScreenTakeOver` property not working: How can I keep an FLVPlayback out of fullscreen mode in a fullscreen projector?

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen, flash-cs5, flvplayback

I have an FLVPlayback component on my timeline (frame 4 or so), and my Flash Projector is running in fullscreen mode. The problem is that I can't seem to make my FLVPlayback component NOT be in fullscreen mode and at the same time, have my stage in fullscreen mode.

Why is this? How do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I want the projector to be in fullscreen mode, and the FLVPlayback to not be in fullscreen.

**EDIT2:**

I'm making an interactive projector in Flash CS5. The projector opens, loads a video into  an FLVPlayback component in the first frame. For some reason, that FLVPlayback component does not take over the screen. (I've called `flv.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` before the video loads. Maybe that's why?)

However, when I try to use an FLVPlayback component in a different frame (frame 4), the video player takes over the screen, showing only a black screen while playing the video. It ignores the `fullScreenTakeOver = false`.

What could be wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: ok... so you want to be in fullscreen mode or not ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, Once you are in full screen then you are in fullscreen with all objects in view.

Comment: @TiMeister - The FLVPlayback component has its own FullScreenTakeOver property.

Comment: from what I know... but I may be wrong the full-screen is applied on stage.... so does not really matthers where you make the FS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's rather easy to resize the `Video` instance to e.g. 25% of stage size on [FullScreenEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FullScreenEvent.html)

**UPD:** [working (but very simple) example on wonderfl.net](http://wonderfl.net/c/xDC1) 
 i check on enter frame, but it's really too often:

```
video.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updSize);
private function updSize(e:Event = null):void{
   video.width = stage.displayState == 'fullScreen' ? smallVidWidth : bigVidWidth;
   video.height = stage.displayState == 'fullScreen' ? smallVidHeight : bigVidHeight;
}
```

imho it's always possible to know when the displayState is changed, but even using a timer would be better then enterframe

Comment: Yes, but it's a multi-frame SWF and the FullScreenEvent is called only when the projector opens. The FLVPlayback component appears much later.

Comment: @Moshe: then you can check displystate when it appears

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using an FLVPlayback Component, not a Video instance. Maybe I can switch to video though...

Comment: @Moshe: it could be any DisplayObject - anything with width and height

Comment: @Moshe: just read your question update and may i ask you: are you sure that using timeline animation in the same file where you have code is the only solution? imho timeline animated flash movies can't handle more code than e.g. function run():void{gotoAndPlay(45); nowPlaying = true;} just to use their graphic and sound resources in some purely coded-one-frame-swf that is just a monochrome rectangle until any recources are loaded of greated. As far as i know there must be problems with communication between the document class and other app when it's displaying not the first frame

Comment: I'm using all the code in the timeline here. I'm not that great with classes and I'm afraid to start messing with classes.

Comment: my statistics show that it takes about a month to get used to all this class stuff. and if you're used to writing code in adobe flash - i think you'll be happy to switch to a normal source code editor with lots of code completion and generation features. and by the way there's another solution - you can still write code in a manner you like, but load all timeline animated elements as separate files (or from library) - it's really easy to manage their animations while they all have one ActionScript version (1 and 2 count as 1). sorry for writing so many symbols - i just love the flash platform

Comment: @Moshe: and what do you pass to your FLVPlayback to make it play? once i started to create a library of useful classes, but i was lazy and busy enough to have only a good working/well tested event model, picture and video loaders/wrappers, some ugly programmly created UIs a half-tested motion tweener, a progress and a scrollbar and a very cute color picker. so let me know if you'd like to take a look

Comment: @www0z0k - Sure, I'd love to take a look.